# Building a switcher feature

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a simple switcher feature.

First of all, the following code is not working. What am I doing wrong here?

Second, can I build it with an if statement instead of using 2 different but similar functions.

edited: I looked at Syon's example and made some changes. What is happening right now is, if originally everyone is selected and if I click on only friends, 'selected' class is properly assigned to only friends and removed from everyone. But if originally only friends is selected, nothing happens.

```
    $(".switcher span").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "content/profile/index.cs.asp?Process=ChangeComm",
            success: function(data) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('public')) { 
                $(".public").addClass('selected');
                $(".limited").removeClass('selected');
            } else {
                $(".limited").addClass('selected');
                $(".public").removeClass('selected');
            }
            return false;
            },
            error: function (data) {                        
            }
        });
    });

    <style>
    .switcher { width:100%; color:white; min-height:20px; padding:5px 0; cursor:pointer; }
    .switcher .selected { font-weight:bold; background:green; }
    .switcher span { width:25%; background: black; padding:5px; border-bottom-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px; border-top-left-radius:5px; border-top-right-radius:5px;   }
    .switcher span.desc { width:50%; color:black; background:white; }
    </style>
        <div class="switcher">
            <span class="desc">güncellemeler</span>
            <span class="public <% If strDisplayComm = 1 Then %>selected<% End If %>">everyone</span>
            <span class="limited <% If strDisplayComm = 0 Then %>selected<% End If %>">only friends</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What part exactly doesn't work? Why not use radio buttons?

Comment: Nothing is triggered when I click on either of the spans

Comment: I cannot not use radio buttons in this scenario because it does not fit with the design

Comment: .selected doesnt have enough specificity. `.switcher .span` has a higher value so it never changes the color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. You need to add more specificity to your css for `.selected` = `.switcher span.selected` and you can use an if to check the class name to perform different actions.

Here's a [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/AYZDL/)

**CSS**

```
.switcher {
    width: 100 %;
    color: white;
    min - height: 20px;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.switcher span {
    padding: 5px;
    background: black;
}
.switcher span.selected {
    background: green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="switcher">
    <span class="public">everyone</span>
    <span class="limited">only friends</span>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".switcher span").on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(".switcher span").removeClass('selected');
    if ($this.hasClass('limited')) {
        //perform ajax
    } else if ($this.hasClass('public')) {
        //perform ajax
    }
    $this.addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: I looked at your example and made changes to my original code. Right now, its partially working. Can you please take a look at the original post again.

Comment: If I copy/paste the contents of the success function in my jsFiddle it still works. May need to check your html or ajax success.